# Is there a way to calculate an optimal route between multiple nodes with different types of travel

Tags: networkx, graph-theory, graph-traversal

In the game EVE Online there is a map with systems, these systems can be traversed by gates or jump drives but there are some limitations:

- If the system is in range (jump drives have a max range based on geographical distance)
- Jump drives can not be used in certain systems
- Certain classes of ships can not enter certain systems
- The jump drive has a cooldown on usage which increases based on how recently you've used it.

The data for the location of systems in space is available, as is the list of gates which connect systems

I'm trying to calculate an optimal route between two systems, I expect most ideal solutions will make use of both gates and the jump drive because gating is riskier and slower (based on size of system which is also data which is available) and jumping is instant but subject to a cooldown which increases based on how many times you've jumped with the cooldown.

I'm aware there are likely to be numerous solutions to this problem, I've used [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/) in the past but I'm struggling to understand how I would express the limitations I have in a library like NetworkX, it seems like cost is the way to go about this? but I don't know if it is enough to model this problem?

I'm not looking for someone to give me a complete solution, just hoping for some pointers on if NetworkX is the right way to go, academic research in the same area etc.

Answer (score 0):

- Construct a graph with vertices representing "systems".
- Remove vertices representing systems that your ship cannot enter
- Add edges between every pair of vertices that are within jump range of each other
- Add edges between every pair of vertices that are connected by a "gate"
- Apply Dijkstra algorithm to find your path between systems

This will give you a feasible path.  It may not be "ideal".  Since you have not told us what makes a path more or less ideal, it is hard to say more.  You hint that there may be costs involved.  Perhaps "gates" are more or less expensive than "jumps" - in which case you adjust the edge weights appropriately and Dijkstra will give you the cheapest path.

---

*Edge cost depends on previous path.*

[image]

If the cost of C-D depends on which of A or B are on the path, there are two ways to handle it:

*for simple, small problems*

Modify the graph:

[image]

*for large complex problems*

Modify the code to calculate the cost on the fly by examining the current path to the node being visited, rather than just looking it up in a table of edge costs.

Comment: I understand I can weight the path finding process using cost, how would I adjust the cost based on if they'd already jumped or gated (and had no cooldown etc).

Comment: You will have to clarify that comment.  You really have to tell us what makes a path more or less ideal i.e. what function you want to optimize.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit my post. Basically - gating is riskier and slower, jumping is instant but subject to a cooldown which increases based on how many times you've jumped with the cooldown. So the ideal route is a mix of gating/jumping

Comment: So, you are trying to optimize the travel time?

Comment: Or perhaps some combination of travel time and risk.  Again, you need to specify the function you want to optimize, not just provide vague hints about it.

Comment: You need to write a function that captures the trade off between risk and time.  e.g. cutting time by 1 time unit is worth  increasing the risk by 0.05.  The you can apply the formula to get a weight for each connection and finally Dijkstra will give you the optimal path.

Comment: I'm starting to put it together. Like you've said:
Construct a graph
Remove vertices for systems we can't go into
Add edges

Extra: Assign a time calculation for gating and the jump delay

I don't think I can just use the NetworkX  function for path though - https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.dijkstra_path.html it takes in a weight function which seems to only share the edge, there is no context on the path it has taken to get there, so you don't know if you should apply cost for jump edges

Comment: Added to answer two ways to handle "context"